# How to execute bash script without password?

Tags: linux, bash, arch-linux

I need to execute the script after system boot. For example:

```
(sleep 5 && (sudo dhcpcd wlp4s0))
```

What I need: Executing the script. What I have: [sudo] password for eugene: I has been edited /etc/sudoers so:

```
eugene ALL=NOPASSWD: /home/eugene/dhcpcdstart.sh
```

But it's ineffectually. How I can to execute the current script without password? Arch Linux 2013.05.01

Comment: You should learn about the init scripts on Arch. I believe it uses systemd. Look up how to run scripts on startup using systemd. (When you find out, come back and post the answer. You are allowed and encouraged to answer your own questions. =D)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, listen to what @daviewales said and do this properly using the init system. It's as simple as:

```
systemctl enable dhcpcd@wlp4s0.service
```

Second, your sudoers modification doesn't work because you've added the wrong path there.

- You added `/home/eugene/dhcpcdstart.sh` to sudoers...
- ...but you're running `sudo dhcpcd`, i.e. `sudo /usr/bin/dhcpcd`.

Comment: Yes, but I need to start one script mode fur fully wifi working.
Second script: sudo wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlp4s0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
And second script should starting before dhcpcd. So I used the scripts, I don't know how to start this combination.